# Expected absolute value of the difference between a random variable and its mean

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be a random variable with mean $\mu$ and probability density function $f(x)$.

The standard deviation $\sigma$ is usually defined as the root of the variance:

$$\sigma = \sqrt{\int_{-\infty}^\infty (x - \mu)^2  f(x) \,dx}$$

But how would one interpret the following term:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x - \mu|  f(x) \,dx \,\,?$$

Surely this expression is not equal to $\sigma$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression is also a measure of dispersion. In fact it is a distance between the data points and $\mu$. It is not optimal becasuse (it is easy to prove) that the minimum distance

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(x-A)^2f_X(x)dx$$

is achieved when $A=\mu$

On the other hand, an optimal indicator is achieved when

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x-Me|f_X(x)dx$$

Where $Me$ indicates the median. This indicator is called Median absolute deviation

Answer (score 1):

That is the [*average absolute deviation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average_absolute_deviation) from the mean.

It is less than or equal to the standard deviation (with equality when $X$ has support on only two values with equal probability, or takes only one value with probability $1$, not having a density in those cases),

but greater than or equal to the average absolute deviation from the median (with equality when the mean is a median).